# Keep CSV commas inside fields with Python

Tags: python, csv

I've got a lot of auto-generated CSV files that are all structured like this:

```
id,movie,actors
1,title1,actor1,actor2
2,title2,actor1,actor2
```

Now when I try to load the actors column in Python with this:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
      actors = row['actors']
```

I got my actor1 and actor2 for each row, but they don't have comma anymore, so I can't split them and consider as 2 different actors. Unfortunally I don't have the option to change the field separator in the CSV because it's auto generated. Any ideas on how to keep the comma inside the field data?

Comment: Is it collapsing them together with no character between the two names at all? Also is there always just 2 actors? Because then you could just add another actors column in the header.

Comment: do I understand correctly that there are always id and movie fields at the start and variable list of actors afterwards? Can movie title contain comma (if not how would I know that this is ending of movie title instead of the first actor)? Most likely I would replace two first commas in a string with something else (say ; ), then split the string based on that symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DictReader` just needs to be configured a bit differently and it should then work as you needed. Based on your example data above, and a csv looking as follows:

csv file contents

```
1,title1,actor1,actor2
2,title2,actor1,actor2
3,title3,actor1,actor2,actor3
```

The following should work...

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",", fieldnames=["id","movie"], restkey="actors")
    for row in reader:
        actors = row['actors']
```

`actors` would then hold a list as follows:

```
['actor1', 'actor2']
```

If you want to keep it with commas:

```
print ",".join(actors)
```

You can then also access the other two fields as follows:

```
row['id']
row['movie']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use maxsplit argument to split in a following way:

```
with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    id, movie, actor_list = line.strip().split(maxsplit = 2)
    actors = actor_list.split()
    .... do something with id, movie, actors
```